# What do the scriptures say about the eight generals of Lord Rama?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, rama, yoga-vashishtha, vibhishana

I am currently reading the Yog Vasishth and it is throwing up a lot of interesting details. In **[Chapter 2 of Book 1](https://archive.org/stream/YogaVasishtaOfValmikiValmiki/Yoga%20Vasishta%20of%20Valmiki%20-%20Valmiki#page/n51/mode/2up)** we find the following statement:

> 28-29 The eight ministers of Rama — **Dhrishta, Jayanta, Bhasa, Satya, Vijaya, Vibishanah, Sushena and Hanumana,** and also Indrajita — are said to have been equally dispassionate in their minds and content with what was their lot. They were great souls, free in their lives.

I know Sushen and Hanuman were Vanar chiefs and Vibhishan was the newly appointed saintly king of Lanka **But I want to know about the other five.** Are there any details in scriptures about them?

Comment: You answered the question who were eight generals in the question itself. You should edit the title to something like "What are the details of eight generals of Rama?" or similar.

Comment: Ya that's what i mentioned in the question body. Will edit the title too.

Comment: They were  the  ministers with the help of whom Dasharatha was ruling his kingdom . May be Rama also carried them forward in  his rule.

Comment: Oh you mean the first five were Dashrath's ministers that continued serving Rama as well? Can you please share the references as an answer?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal - http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga7/bala_7_frame.htm

Comment: Yes , i will post the answer with original sanskrit shlokas only if I found Rama appointing them again in Uttar-Ramayana or somewhere else.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar sounds good. BTW I think only three names are similar out of the list - Dhristi, Jayantha & Vijaya

Comment: What? When did Hanuman become Rama's general? Did he desert his leader Sugriva? Indrajit died in the war. What's he doing in Ayodhya? Makes me wonder if Yoga Vasistha has anything to do with Valmiki Ramayana at all.

Comment: @sv. not sure about Hanuman but we really don't know what happened later. Uttar Kand also has similar doubts relating to its authenticity so I guess both scriptures stand at the same level. BTW Indrajit is not mentioned amongst the 8 he is just named after them.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I think except that Balakanda they are not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I think you can answer with quote. I searched quite a bit but couldn't find any other info. You can answer with that quote.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal: Ramayana ends with the episode of coronation of Sri Rama as the king of Kosala Kingdom.  A [6th century Ramayana](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/kolkata/6th-century-Ramayana-found-in-Kolkata-stuns-scholars/articleshow/50227724.cms), found in Kokatta , confirms that Uttara Kanda is an interpolated story.

Comment: I certainly believe that to be the case.. there are too many glitches in the Uttar Ramayan story that dont match with the main body of the text.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[Source: Khemraj Shree Krishnadas Prakashan]

The 8 mantri are listed, but the context is clearly about becoming a jeevan-mukta and not a ministerial post.

Mantri (Sanskrit: मन्त्री) is a word of Sanskrit origin (meaning sage, i.e. the "person who thinks and says" in that language, cf. Mantra), and it is used for a variety of public offices, from fairly humble to ministerial in rank [Source: http://dictionary.sensagent.com/mantri/en-en/].

sanskritdictionary.com also translates mantri as wise/ eloquent/ knowing sacred texts/ minister.

I think, in this context Rishi Valmiki is referring to mantri as a jeevan-mukta knower of mantra.